# How to split a string on a pattern match

Tags: regex, string, perl

I have the following string,

```
9.2 20268 pat 6.0 24977 pat 4.0 21222 pat 3.9 20854 pat
```

I need to split this string and save the resulting strings in an array.

the resulting strings would look like the following:

```
9.2 20268 pat
6.0 24977 pat
4.0 21222 pat
3.9 20854 pat
```

Please can someone help me with this ?

Comment: Have you any attempts yet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this regex for split:

```
(?<=pat)\s+
```

- `(?<=pat)` is the lookbehind regex that makes sure 1 or more spaces are preceded by literal string `pat`

**Example:**

```
perl -wpe 's/(?<=pat)\s+/\n/g' <<< "9.2 20268 pat 6.0 24977 pat 4.0 21222 pat 3.9 20854 pat"
9.2 20268 pat
6.0 24977 pat
4.0 21222 pat
3.9 20854 pat
```

Comment: Thank you very much, please could you elaborate on the regex? I guess the ?<=pat matches the pattern pat and then \s (is this for splitting the string?)

Comment: @user2986175: Yes I had added explanation just before Example. `(?<=pat) is the lookbehind pattern that makes sure 1 or more spaces are preceded by literal string "pat" for splitting`.

Answer (score 3):

you can use this fixed "pat" as a split delimiter.

```
perl -wpe 's/pat\s/pat\n/g' <<< "9.2 20268 pat 6.0 24977 pat 4.0 21222 pat 3.9 20854 pat"
9.2 20268 pat
6.0 24977 pat
4.0 21222 pat
3.9 20854 pat
```

or

```
perl -wpe 's|pat\K\s|\n|g' <<< "9.2 20268 pat 6.0 24977 pat 4.0 21222 pat 3.9 20854 pat"
```

[perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#%28?%3C=pattern%29-%5CK) for `\K` look-around assertion.

Comment: +1. I prefer to avoid complex regex wherever possible and this is exactly what your answer does.